# 大文字は小文字に、小文字は大文字に、それ以外の文字は*に変換するプログラム

Tags: c

タイトルの通り、大文字を小文字に、小文字を大文字に変換するプログラムを作成することは容易なのですが、
それ以外の文字を*で表現すべくプログラムをどうやったら作成できるのかがわかりません。

とりあえず、自分が現段階で作成したプログラムを示します。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXSTRLEN 32
void str_change(char str[])
{
    int i=0;
    while(str[i]!='\0'){
        if('A'<=str[i] && str[i]<='Z'){
            str[i]=str[i]-'A'+'a';
        }  else if('a'<=str[i] && str[i]<='z'){
            str[i]=str[i]-'a'+'A';
        }   \\ここに*の手続きをすると考えている。
        i++;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char str[MAXSTRLEN];

    printf("文字列? ");
    scanf("%s", str);

    str_change(str);
    printf("変換後: %s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

現段階での実行結果
$ ./a.out
文字列? great!!
変換後: GREAT!!
$ ./a.out
文字列? GREAT!!
変換後: great!!

期待する実行結果
$ ./a.out
文字列? GREAT!!
変換後: great**

初めは「else {str[i]=* ;}」みたいなことを考えたのですが、当然正しいはずもなくエラーが出てしまいました。
勉強不足ですみませんが、どうやったら条件を満たすプログラムを作成できるのでしょうか。

Comment: ちなみに問題と直接関係は無いですが、何か標準関数を極力使わない縛りでも課しているのでしょうか？ 変換処理の中に記述している内容は、例えばこちらの関数を使った方が分かりやすくなると思われます。[C言語 文字列の長さを取得](http://simd.jugem.jp/?eid=123), [C言語 大文字判定 小文字判定](http://simd.jugem.jp/?eid=108), [C言語 文字判定 大文字 小文字変換](http://simd.jugem.jp/?eid=16)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 初めは「else {str[i]=* ;}」みたいなことを考えたのですが、当然正しいはずもなくエラーが出てしまいました。

タイポ(入力間違い)でなければ、
else {str[i]='*';} 　　を試してみてはどうでしょう。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。　*に '   '  をつけるという初歩的なことが思いつきませんでした。